# Mysterious white space on the right hand side

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap, and whenever my page is resize to < 992 px, the following happened.

The code for the red bar is

```
<body>
    <div style="background:red;height:20px;width:100%;"></div>
```

Nothing special, not inside a container.

Even if I put the following CSS doesn't help either

```
html,body {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
```

[image]

I am sure it is some settings of bootstrap that causes this but couldn't figure out what is the cause.

Comment: Any live link where we can see things?

Comment: do u have a fiddle link or screenshot if any ?

Comment: Works for me: http://jsbin.com/bawuwiruhaki/1/

Answer (score 1):

This could be caused by `@media` queries defined in bootstrap css. You need to override them in your own css file or just edit it in bootstrap css file (but thats bad practice, because you can't update lets say to newer version of bootstrap styles without making these changes all over again)